# Array List clears in JSonArrayReques

Tags: android, arraylist, android-volley

I am using volley to get an JSon response back. In the code what I am doing is, I am reading person data in to an ArrayList of type Person. A person has a name and a surname that can be set using setters. For some reason the array list populates in the code but it is cleared at a point in the code.

```
    String MainURL = glob.getURL();
    //string Bulder
    URLBuild.append(MainURL).append("api/gt");

    final ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
    final String URL = URLBuild.toString();
    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                int length = response.length();
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    Person p = new Person();
                    p.setName(jsonItems.getString("Name"));
                    p.setSName(jsonItems.getString("SName"));
                    list.add(p);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

   //after this point the array list is blank again
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e(error);
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //
            return null;
        }
    };

    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    Spinner ArrayToSpin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayToSpin.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

I used toasts to see what the content of the list is latter on in the application and it is blank after the point marked in the code.

I cant seem to find where and why the array list is cleared or blank.

Comment: FIrst, pls check IF loop exctuted or not, try to put Log.i(...) inside it. Second, what is the `jsonItems`? Where did you initialize this variable?